# Have a second directory serve static content

Tags: django

Currently I'm converting a site from a very old version of Joomla to Django.  There are some hardcoded files in SWF which point to /media directory and, of course, we do not have the FLA's

How do I add /media endpoint to point to directory static/media ?

Thanks

Comment: You are better off doing this kind of rewrite at web server level.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in the settings.py file.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Above lines will render the media files during development.

For production, you should handle from the web server just like you would do for static files.